# How to get an email address with jsoup

Tags: android, html, parsing, email, jsoup

I have a table like this

```
 <TR BGCOLOR="#F9F9F9">
            <TD width="1%" nowrap><B>Tel:</B></TD>
            <TD>+39 04949 59599</TD>
            <TD width="1%" nowrap><B>Email:</B></TD>
            <TD><A HREF="javascript:void(0);"
                OnClick="Messenger('/do/home.pl/Messenger?email=mailaddress@gmail.com')">mailaddress@gmail.com</a></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR BGCOLOR="#F9F9F9">
            <TD width="1%" nowrap><B>Fax:</B></TD>
            <TD>+39 304040 303030</TD>
            <TD width="1%" nowrap><B>Skype:</B></TD>
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
```

I need to get that mail address, but I have some problems because my code give me back an empty text. I tried to parse the entire text of the table but the result was all the text except that mail! the same if I parse that td or I use index in order to find that a href element. How can I solve this?

This is code I tried

```
    Element info1 = doc.select("table").get(7); //this works
    Elements td = info1.select("td");
    String telefono="";
    String email="";    
Element tdtel=info1.select("td").get(1);
telefono = "Tel. :" + tdtel.text(); //this works
Element tdmail=info1.select("td").get(3);
Element linkmail =tdmail.select("a[href]").first(); //error here
```

Comment: Seeing some code would make an answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
Elements elements = doc.select("A[HREF=javascript:void(0);]");
System.out.println(elements.get(0).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the content of the `a` tag, try

```
Element linkmail =tdmail.select("a");
String mail = linkmail.text();
```